# Cannot Connect to SQL Server from Another Computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have been going at this for hours, but have had no success with the current posts out there.

Tried methods:

- Enabling TCP
- Allowing Remote Connections for the database
- Adding new inbound and outbound rules

All these things still do not let me login from my other computer. When I connect on my main computer, everything is instant, but when I tried on my secondary one, it takes a long time before giving me the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

Is there anyway of fixing this? I don't think watching more Youtube tutorials will help.

Comment: What does your connection string used look like? What's the name of the remote computer where you have SQL Server installed? And what **version** (2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019) and which **edition** (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise, Developer) is installed there?

Comment: After enabling TCP/IP in server protocols, or changing address and port assignments there, did you restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect? Also, your client appears to be using Named Pipes Provider. You may wish to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67881408/edit) your question to include your Connection String so that suggestions can be made to change it to use TCP/IP sockets.

Comment: Use `netstat -a` on the server to make sure sqls is listening, typically on port 1433. Can you telnet into that port from thelocal machine? Can you telnet into it from the remote? Can you ping the server using the same name as is in the connection string? (checking name lookup works)(not applicable if you're using up address)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yeah i did

Comment: If I were you, I would disable the firewall in the sql server host to check if the problem is there. When checked, enable it again adding a rule for your sql server instance.

Comment: First get working with SQL Server Management Studio which will give better error messages than in c#.  If your connection string is using Integrated Security is true than make sure the login window in SSMS shows Window Credential.  If you are using a user name and password than make sure SSMS show SQL Credentials.  When connecting to a remote machine you cannot use LocaldB.  So remove Attachdb from the connection string. Also when you are using Window Credentials you need to use the same account on local and remote machine. In a company you would be using Group Policy.  Post connection string.

Comment: no, i am logging in directly from SSMS from another computer, and it gives me this error. @jdweng

Comment: You have a credentials issue.  Are you logging in using Windows Credentials or SQL Credentials?  What credentials are you using when it is working locally?  Is mdf attached to a SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Credentials. I am using the same ones I use to login locally. No clue about mdf one though @jdweng

Comment: It would help to see connection string (you can edit to remove personal info).  If you are using windows credentials you have to use same account on both machines.  So the two computers have to be in the same group (Group Policy).  And the credentials of the database has to be the group.  Locally in SSMS you can check the security tab to check the credentials of the database.  You may have to add another credential to the database to get working.  First make sure you can get SSMS to work from remote machine before trying c#.

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I have been trying to login to SSMS from my other computer, but it doesn't work. Any fix?

Comment: If you want to use widows credentials the two machines have to be part of a workgroup.  See : https://www.digitalcitizen.life/workgroup-windows/ or in a corporate network use Group Policy.